# Problem with grep on multiple files and not getting desired output

Tags: linux, grep, head, header-file, more

I am using the below command on a file to extract few lines based on chr# ( different chromosome numbers). This is just a single file am working on. i have 8 such files and for each file I have to do this for chr(1to 22 and then chrX and chrY) , am not using any loop, I did it invidually , but if you see that I want the header to be intact for each of my output. If I execute individually I get the header in the output but if am running but if I run the script for all the 8 files together which is like 8*24 commands in a script one after another, the output does not have any header. Can you tell me why is this happening?

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#$ -N DOC_gatk_chr
#$ -cwd
#$ -e err_DOC_gatk_chr.txt
#$ -o out_DOC_gatk_chr.txt
#$ -S /bin/sh
#$ -M vivek.das@ieo.eu
#$ -m bea
#$ -l h_vmem=25G

more S_313_IPS_S7995.coverage.sample_interval_summary | head -n1; more S_313_IPS_S7995.coverage.sample_interval_summary | grep "chr1" > S_313_IPS_S7995.chr1.coverage
more S_313_IPS_S7995.coverage.sample_interval_summary | head -n1; more S_313_IPS_S7995.coverage.sample_interval_summary | grep "chr2" > S_313_IPS_S7995.chr2.coverage
more S_313_IPS_S7995.coverage.sample_interval_summary | head -n1; more S_313_IPS_S7995.coverage.sample_interval_summary | grep "chr3" > S_313_IPS_S7995.chr3.coverage
more S_313_IPS_S7995.coverage.sample_interval_summary | head -n1; more S_313_IPS_S7995.coverage.sample_interval_summary | grep "chr4" > S_313_IPS_S7995.chr4.coverage
more S_313_IPS_S7995.coverage.sample_interval_summary | head -n1; more S_313_IPS_S7995.coverage.sample_interval_summary | grep "chr5" > S_313_IPS_S7995.chr5.coverage
more S_313_IPS_S7995.coverage.sample_interval_summary | head -n1; more S_313_IPS_S7995.coverage.sample_interval_summary | grep "chr6" > S_313_IPS_S7995.chr6.coverage
more S_313_IPS_S7995.coverage.sample_interval_summary | head -n1; more S_313_IPS_S7995.coverage.sample_interval_summary | grep "chr7" > S_313_IPS_S7995.chr7.coverage
more S_313_IPS_S7995.coverage.sample_interval_summary | head -n1; more S_313_IPS_S7995.coverage.sample_interval_summary | grep "chr8" > S_313_IPS_S7995.chr8.coverage
more S_313_IPS_S7995.coverage.sample_interval_summary | head -n1; more S_313_IPS_S7995.coverage.sample_interval_summary | grep "chr9" > S_313_IPS_S7995.chr9.coverage
```

Am running it as a job with qsub so the structure of the script looks like above. It works if I execute the commands individually but if I run them like this , the header does not get printed in the output file, the ';' is not recognized it seems. I tried to ran it with both qsub filename.sh and sh filename.sh. I found that with sh filename.sh the header gets printed in the console. So definitely the command before';' semi-colon is not being written in the file. How can I get rid of this problem.

Desired output:

```
Target  total_coverage  average_coverage    IPS_S7995_total_cvg IPS_S7995_mean_cvg  IPS_S7995_granular_Q1   IPS_S7995_granular_median   IPS_S7995_granular_Q3   IPS_S7995_%_above_15
chr2:41460-41683    14271   63.71   14271   63.71   56  67  79  100.0
chr2:45338-46352    123888  122.06  123888  122.06  79  123 147 94.6
chr2:218731-218983  11653   46.06   11653   46.06   36  50  55  100.0
chr2:224825-225012  12319   65.53   12319   65.53   57  68  76  100.0
chr2:229912-230090  20983   117.22  20983   117.22  93  120 147 100.0
chr2:230947-231137  22386   117.20  22386   117.20  100 120 139 100.0
chr2:233074-233258  11710   63.30   11710   63.30   54  66  73  100.0
chr2:234086-234300  22952   106.75  22952   106.75  91  113 126 100.0
chr2:242747-242922  20496   116.45  20496   116.45  93  124 142 100.0
chr2:243469-243671  27074   133.37  27074   133.37  126 138 148 100.0
```

But output am getting is below without the header

```
chr2:41460-41683    14271   63.71   14271   63.71   56  67  79  100.0
chr2:45338-46352    123888  122.06  123888  122.06  79  123 147 94.6
chr2:218731-218983  11653   46.06   11653   46.06   36  50  55  100.0
chr2:224825-225012  12319   65.53   12319   65.53   57  68  76  100.0
chr2:229912-230090  20983   117.22  20983   117.22  93  120 147 100.0
chr2:230947-231137  22386   117.20  22386   117.20  100 120 139 100.0
chr2:233074-233258  11710   63.30   11710   63.30   54  66  73  100.0
chr2:234086-234300  22952   106.75  22952   106.75  91  113 126 100.0
chr2:242747-242922  20496   116.45  20496   116.45  93  124 142 100.0
chr2:243469-243671  27074   133.37  27074   133.37  126 138 148 100.0
```

Comment: "If I execute individually I get the header" What header? Why don't you show us both the output you get and the output you expect / want?

Comment: Also consider simplifying it by removing `more` and giving the files as arguments directly to `head` and `grep`.

Comment: I try to do a kind of troubleshooting and I found that when I am running the command individually it is working but if I am running with qsub as a job the headers are not getting appended in the output file.

Comment: @HaukeLaging . I have already edited the question. Can you please take a look now and let me know if its clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
{ head -n1 S_313_IPS_S7995.coverage.sample_interval_summary; 
  grep "chr1" S_313_IPS_S7995.coverage.sample_interval_summary; } >S_313_IPS_S7995.chr1.coverage
```

or

```
awk 'NR==1 || /chr1/' S_313_IPS_S7995.coverage.sample_interval_summary >S_313_IPS_S7995.chr1.coverage
```

The problem is that the redirection affects only one command. In order to get the output of `head` and `grep` in the redirection they have to be grouped. But `awk` is probably the better choice here.

Comment: I used the previous one even that one works out. `{ head -n1; grep "chr1"; } <S_333_IPS_S7997.coverage.sample_interval_summary >S_333_IPS_S7997.chr1.coverage`

Comment: @vchris_ngs I was afraid that might not work because `head` reads more than the first line. But an input redirection is seekable so `head` resets to the position `grep` should see. It does not work with `cat file | { head ...`. But it would be safe to use the shell bulitin `read`: `{ IFS= read -r line; echo "$line"; grep ...;} <...`

Comment: yes it does not work with cat but with it did work here. anyway I will keep this in mind will use awk for such actions. Thanks a lot. But yes heads work with first link this case so it worked out properly